# Can carbon dioxide be used as oxidant for iron?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

Determine whether it is possible for $\ce{CO2}$ to be an oxidant for $\ce{Fe}$. Justify your choice by comparing the corresponding half reactions.

I found the following half-reactions, both on reduction form:

\begin{align}
\tag{I}\label{I}
 \ce{Fe^2+ + 2e^- &<=> Fe(s)} & E^\circ &= \pu{-0.44 V}\\
\tag{II}\label{II}
 \ce{CO2(g) + 2H^+ + 2e^- &<<=> CO(g) + H2O}& E^\circ &= \pu{-0.1 V}
\end{align}

As iron should be oxidized, we turn \eqref{I} the other way and change the sign:

\begin{align}
\ce{Fe(s) &<=> Fe^2+ + 2e^-}& E^\circ &= \pu{0.44V}\\
&&E^\circ(\text{total}) &= \pu{0.44 V} - \pu{0.1 V} = \pu{0.34V}
\end{align}

$E^\circ(\text{total}) > 0$, and the reaction is spontaneous. But according to the solution manual $E^\circ(\text{total})$ should be less than $0$. Have I misinterpreted the task?

Comment: @HarshWasnik We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: Anyone able to help me ?